# DLL load failed in opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv

I wish if anyone could give me a hand with my prob,
I have installed python 3.6 amd64 and add it to path then installed opencv 3.2 successfully using "pip" ... However, when I'm trying to import the cv2 (the library of opencv) and here is the error that I have got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The module specified is not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `cv2.pyd` is in your `Python's` `lib\site-packages\` directory.

Also check if `OPENCV_DIR` = `C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.2.0\x64\vc14`, or similar, is in your Windows' `system variables` setting. The sample path `OPENCV_DIR` is for the binary compiled with `VC14` which is `Visual Studio 2015 VC++`.

Comment: Do I have to install the vs 2015 cause what I've installed was the vs 2017 and for the path I have it already as well as the cv2.pyd which is located the Python's lib\site-packages. Btw, I didn't get what u've meant with the sample path ...

Comment: You don't need the full VS 2015 installed just the redistributable package : https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=48145 that includes the required C++ runtime

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've installed pip2(for python2) instead of pip3.(for python3)
Try this to install pip for python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Now use

```
pip3 install python3-opencv
```

Comment: pip works very well cause I installed NumPy and matplotlib with it, then I import it and it works well